# HTTP framework for a python based server serving mobile applications

Tags: python, mongodb, web-frameworks, cherrypy, web.py

I am working on building a python powered back-end server for a mobile application. I am using MongoDB hosted on the Cloud for storage. The communication between the Application and the server will be mostly **JSON**. There **wont be any HTML** involved in this transfer as such.

I am looking for a framework to build my server. I did some research and found (**django**, **Pylons** etc) are for **full stack server** and is not needed for my requirements.

I am confused on how to go about selecting an HTTP framework (web.py, cherrypy etc).

also, i might use **Mongoengine** as the ODM. I am not sure if this decision is anyway going to affect the framework selection

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/) or [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), both of which are very minimal and impose no constraints on you whatsoever. In the case of bottle, it's particularly easy to build a simple RESTful server since it will automatically return JSON from a route that returns a dict:

```
from bottle import route, run

@route('/user_info/:id'):
def user_info(id):
    user = get_user(id)  # ...do something, lookup user, whatever
    return {'first_name': user.first_name, 'last_name': user.last_name}

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Pyramid Framework](http://pylonsproject.org) doesnt enforce a templating engine (**not a full stack**) or a persistence/storage system. It has [json](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/dev/narr/renderers.html#json-json-renderer) and [jsonp](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/dev/narr/renderers.html#jsonp-renderer) renderer (no html at all).

It also has a [scaffold](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_jqm) for jquery mobile app (I havent tried this, so I dont know).

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer web.py, but in your case it is possible to start with basic wsgi app, or something simple as http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/ because it doesn't enforce a specific template engine or database adapter.